# Website in Docker available outside network

Tags: docker

I got a container running, that I access through localhost:80, and it shows the web app I expected. I used -p 80:80 to expose the port:

[image: Print of Container running]

I need to allow other people (in other networks) to access the web app.

They should be able to access it by typing my IP:port, right? Example 192.168.x.x:80

They are receiving an error message when trying to access it.

I tried:

-Adding inbound rules to my Firewall

-Changing from bridge network to a network I created.

I looked up but couldn't find any other possible reasons that they can't access. Am I getting this all wrong? What should I do to allow other networks to reach my site?

Comment: Try this `-p 192.168.X.X:80:80`, or this `-p 0.0.0.0:80:80`

Comment: I tried but it didn't work.